# Are infinities of uncountable sets same?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory, infinity

I know, in Mathematics all infinities are not same for example, cardinality of natural numbers and cardinality of real numbers are two different infinities. But I want to know, can two uncountable sets have two different infinities in terms of their size ?

Comment: Here is one place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set#Examples

Comment: The power set of any infinite set is a higher order of infinity than the set itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any set, [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem)
says its [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) (set of subsets) is larger. This set's existence is taken as an axiom in many popular set theories. There's also a [more complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number) way to construct a set larger than a given one.

Comment: Ok, so from here we can always find two uncountable sets with no bijection between them.

Comment: @ManojKumar More than two: infinitely many! Because if $X$ is uncountable, then $\mathcal{P}(X)$, $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$, $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X)))$, $\dots$ are all different cardinalities.

Comment: The concept of Hartogs number I linked to allows us to show, in fact, that there are not only uncountably many infinities, but as large an uncountable infinity of them as you'd like.

Comment: How does the concept of a Hartogs number provide that while iterated power sets don't? Just take unions at limit stages.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You're right, you could do something like $S_{\alpha+1}=\mathcal{P}(S_\alpha),\,S_{\gamma}=\bigcup_{\beta\in\gamma}S_\beta$ for nonzero limit ordinals $\gamma$. Either way, you'll need to be aware of ordinals. I guess what Hartogs numbers really give you is the awareness that, because given every set $S$ there's an ordinal larger than $S$, we know there have to be so many ordinals that, in fact, we can have "as large an uncountable infinity of [infinities] as you'd like". But then, who am I kidding? You could make much of the same point with Burali-Forti.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But a simpler way of doing this style of diagonalization is by realizing that given any set of sets, the power set of their union is larger in cardinality.